# Could not denormalize object of type, no supporting normalizer found. Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize between json and doctrine entity but keep getting this error

> "Could not denormalize object of type AppBundle/Person, no supporting
> normalizer found. "

My entity class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Person
{
    private $age;
    private $name;

    // Getters
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

    // Setters
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setAge($age)
    {
        $this->age = $age;
    }

}
```

My controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use AppBundle\Entity\Person;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;

class RawGrnController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(Request $request)
    {
        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer(),new  GetSetMethodNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $data =$data = <<<EOF
        <person>
            <name>foo</name>
            <age>99</age>
        </person>
        EOF;

        $person = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Person', 'xml');

        $reaponse = new Response($person);
        return $reaponse;
    }
}
```

I got this code from the official Symfony documentation [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/serializer.html#deserializing-an-object).I have tried to use this in my real project and got the above error then, I tried the example on the documentation but still getting the same error.

**Things I've tried so far**

- Serialize an object to json/xml and tried to deserialize it again
- Decode json/xml to an array and then denormalize to an object(decode is successful but denormalizing gives the same error)
- Tried to use serializer as a service as described in [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/serializer.html)

I have no clue what I'm missing to get the normalizer to work. Objects in my project are far more complex but I'm getting bit suspicious as the example in documentation gives the same error. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `$person = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'AppBundle\Entity\Person', 'xml');`? Note the namespace

Comment: @ka_lin Yes but the same error appears

Comment: `$person = $serializer->deserialize($data, Person::class, 'xml');`  This did the trick for me but I don't know how to explain this behavior. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 20):

For future generations, if you inject the serializer into the controller in order to deserialize a POST request body (for example) and you have this error, you probably just imported `symfony/serializer` and forgot to import `symfony/serializer-pack`

more information on [How to use the serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html)

Comment: Straight to the point. Thanks for saving time.